# Hide an imageview by clicking it?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

When tapping a specific button in my app I want an image to show, I did this using an UIImageView. Then I want to hide that image by tapping it, but I don't understand how to do this?

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
@implementation ViewController
-(IBAction)pic {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
[ImageView setImage:img];

imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
//handle tap
}
```

Comment: You should move all of the code out of the IBAction and into the the main class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty simple.

Use an UIImageView instead and check that userInteractionEnabled is YES on the UIImageView. Then you can then add a gesture recognizer.

1. Your .h file should have atleast something like below:

   ```
   #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *touchImageView;

   @end
   ```

Dont forget to connect UIImageView from your storyboard to property declared above.

in your .m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.touchImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                        initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.touchImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
  }

- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer {
//handle tap
self.touchImageView.alpha = 0.0f;
}
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer. Unfortunately I can't get it to work (I'm a beginner at this, sorry). Could you take a look at your code that I added to my original question?

Comment: @JohanGrip Updated my answer.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much @Zhr. Although there is one problem; it only work once, when I tap the button a second time the image doesn't show. I guess this might have to do with the alpha now set to 0?

Comment: Glad it worked. Please accept the solution as answer if it worked for you.

Comment: @JohanGrip Could you elaborate on what do you mean by second time and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want an image to appear when the user taps a button, then I want the user to be able to hide that image by tapping it (all this works now after you helped me). But, I want the image to appear everytime the user taps the button. Now it only works one time. After the image has been shown and hidden once, nothing happens when I press the button again. Unless I restart the app.

Comment: @JohanGrip when user taps a button check if uiiamgeview alpha value is 0, if 0 set it to 1.

Answer (score 0):

You could put an image on a button instead. I think using a UIImageView is the right decision though. You need to hook up a gesture to it programmatically. You can do this using something similar to below:

```
    let singleFingerTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "viewTapped:")
    imageView.addGestureRecognizer(singleFingerTap)
```

Comment: This won't work since image views don't respond to user interactions by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a tap gesture recognizer to the UIImageView that contains the image.

```
var tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: <#AnyObject#>, action: <#Selector#>)
```

In the method you assign as the action, just set myImageView.alpha = 0. This should essentially "hide" your image view. You could also set the height of the image view to 0 if you wanted to hide it in that sense.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative could be to import an open-sourced project, such as the [AKImageViewer](https://github.com/aleckretch/AKImageViewer), to get posts to appear full screen (giving the user a better full view) and allowing them to swipe or cancel to get away from the image (similar to viewing images in the Twitter app.